Precomposing the homology boundary map defines the cohomology boundry map.
Suppose that $X$ is a $\delta$-complex. Take the chain complex whose nth level is $$C_{\Delta}^n(X) = \operatorname{Hom}(C_n^{\Delta}(X), \mathbb Z).$$ I want to show that precomposing the boundary map $\partial_n: C_n^{\Delta}(X) \to C_{n - 1}^{\Delta}(X)$ defines the map $$\delta^n : C_{\Delta}^{n - 1}(X) \to C_{\Delta}^n(X)$$ and that $\delta^{n+1} \delta^n = 0.$
My question is:
1- What map should I exactly precompose with? I am not sure what is the shape of the commutative diagram that I should get.
2-Should I just define a map between 2 chain complexes and then dualize? I know that I will use the property of homology chain complexes that says $\partial \partial = 0.$
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

The easiest way to think about this is to think of $\text{Hom}(\cdot,\Bbb{Z})$ as a (contravariant) functor, with the obvious action on objects and the action on morphisms given by
$$\text{Hom}(g,\Bbb{Z})(f) : = f\circ g.$$
In your case, you want to define $\delta^n:=\text{Hom}(\partial_n,\Bbb{Z})$. Then all your desired properties should come from functoriality. To show that it maps chain complexes to chain complexes, you check that
$$\delta^{n+1}\delta^{n}(f) = (f \circ \partial_n)\circ \partial_{n+1} = f\circ (\partial_n\circ \partial_{n+1}) = f\circ 0 = 0.$$
You can check the Wikipedia page for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor.

Edit: I will give a non-categorical answer, hopefully this answers your questions in the comments.
$C^n_\Delta(X):=\text{Hom}(C_n^\Delta(X),\Bbb{Z}))$ is the set of homomorphisms from $C_n^\Delta(X)$ to $\Bbb{Z}$. We define a map $$\delta^n: C^{n-1}_\Delta(X) \to C^n_\Delta(X)$$
given by precomposition. Let me explain what this means. For a homomorphism $f:C_{n-1}^\Delta(X)\to\Bbb{Z}$, we have that $f\in C^n_\Delta(X)$. Thus, we define the image of $f$ under $\delta^n$ to be
$$\delta^n(f) := f\circ \partial_n,$$
and as $\partial_n$ and $f$ are both homomorphisms, so is their composition, thus $\delta^n(f)$ is a homomorphism from $C_n^\Delta(X)$ to $\Bbb{Z}$, i.e. $\delta^n(f)\in C^n_\Delta(X)$. The fact that $\delta^n$ satisfies $\delta^{n-1}\delta^n = 0$ follows directly from the fact that $\partial_n$ has this property - see my calculation above.

what is the function $g$?

is the map I am precomposing with is just the map between the chain complex and $\mathbb Z$?

what is my $A'$? Which is given in the Wikipedia link? I believe that B is just $\mathbb Z$ in our case, right?

what is "it" in "it maps chain complexes to chain complexes"?

I did not get this statement " with the obvious action on objects on the action on morphisms given by
$$\text{Hom}(g,\Bbb{Z})(f) : = f\circ g.$$" what are the objects here? And how there is an action of objects on morphisms?

but the question wanted me to show that definition not just state it.
